# Is there any difference between catching 0 or 50 boos?

Tags: luigis-mansion

In the story, it is said that every boo you catch weakens king boos influence on the mansion.

But in gameplay terms, is there any changes to the late game of Luigi's Mansion if you caught all the boos or is it only a 100% collectible that only gives a bunch of money?

Is there more than score at stake to catch all boos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Mario wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/List_of_Boos_in_Luigi%27s_Mansion) you need to capture almost all of the Boo's to gain access to different areas of the game.

> Luigi needs to catch 5 Boos to unlock the washroom on the first
>   floor, 20 of them need to be captured to access the balcony on the
>   third floor and battle Boolossus, and 40 of them need to be captured
>   to fight King Boo.

In terms of late game, there doesn't seem to be any information on what else it does, other than giving the gold diamond after you catch all of them.

Comment: Wow it's been a while since I played LM. I completely forgot that they were forced to access the final boss. So yeah the difference between getting only a few and all of them is that you pretty much need them all to finish the game.

Comment: Yeah Ive played this game through many times, the recent playthrough being a couple years ago, and I just now found out you needed them to get through the game.